# Trouble parsing API JSON output with python using 'requests'

Tags: python, json, api, syntax

So i'm trying to get the date and average price of dogecoin (a cryptocurrency, for those unfamiliar) from the vaultofsatoshi.com API using requests and I get an error whenever I try to run the following code

```
import requests
contents = requests.get("https://api.vaultofsatoshi.com/public/ticker?order_currency=DOGE&payment_currency=USD")
print contents.json()[{"data":{"date","average_price"}}]
```

here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "filename", line 5 in <module>
    print contents.json()[{"data":{"date","average_price"}}]
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

to clarify i'm new to API's and the requests module so i am not very familiar with the syntax, any help is greatly appreciated.

edit: fixed a typo with the URL and for reference, this is the dictionary it would return

```
{"status":"success","data":{"date":1392701294,"opening_price":
{"precision":5,"value":"0.00150000","value_int":150},"closing_price":
{"precision":5,"value":"0.00153000","value_int":153},"units_traded":
{"precision":8,"value":"15941676.33311552","value_int":1594167633311552},"max_price":
{"precision":5,"value":"0.00154900","value_int":154},"min_price":
{"precision":5,"value":"0.00141000","value_int":141},"average_price":
{"precision":5,"value":"0.00148","value_int":148},"volume_1day":
{"precision":8,"value":"15941676.33311552","value_int":1594167633311552},"volume_7day":
{"precision":8,"value":"115024501.70386628","value_int":11502450170386628}}}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with `requests`, but you certainly can't use a dictionary (`{"data":{"date","average_price"}}`) as a key to another (presumably) dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Requests response [`.json()`](http://requests.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#json-response-content) method returns a dictionary, of other dictionaries.

First let's look at the JSON object you're getting back. We'll use [`pprint`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html) to pretty-print the results so we can understand their structure.

```
import requests
import pprint

contents = requests.get("https://api.vaultofsatoshi.com/publi/ticker?order_currency=DOGE&payment_currency=USD")

j = contents.json()
pprint.pprint(j)
```

This shows:

```
{u'data': {u'average_price': {u'precision': 5,
                              u'value': u'0.00148',
                              u'value_int': 148},
           u'closing_price': {u'precision': 5,
                              u'value': u'0.00152990',
                              u'value_int': 152},
           u'date': 1392701954,
           u'max_price': {u'precision': 5,
                          u'value': u'0.00154900',
                          u'value_int': 154},
           u'min_price': {u'precision': 5,
                          u'value': u'0.00141000',
                          u'value_int': 141},
           u'opening_price': {u'precision': 5,
                              u'value': u'0.00150000',
                              u'value_int': 150},
           u'units_traded': {u'precision': 8,
                             u'value': u'15946541.33311552',
                             u'value_int': 1594654133311552L},
           u'volume_1day': {u'precision': 8,
                            u'value': u'15946541.33311552',
                            u'value_int': 1594654133311552L},
           u'volume_7day': {u'precision': 8,
                            u'value': u'114969451.70386628',
                            u'value_int': 11496945170386628L}},
 u'status': u'success'}
```

So now, we just need to walk through that data to get what you want. Based on your snippet, I'm guessing you want the date and average_price fields.  Well first, we want the `data` field (although you should probably check the `status` as well).

```
data = j['data']
```

Now, you want the date:

```
from datetime import datetime
dt = datetime.fromtimestamp( data['date'] )
```

And the average price. This however, has several sub-fields. Let's just grab the floating-point version of it, and convert to float:

```
avg_price = float( data['average_price']['value'] )
```

Now print it...

```
print 'Date: {0}   Avg Price: {1}'.format(dt, avg_price)
```

And there you have it:

```
Date: 2014-02-18 00:39:14   Avg Price: 0.00148
```

Comment: I tried, and got a 404. But there's no magic "calling those specifically", unless the API allows it. Did you note how I am iterating and selecting just those pieces of data at the end?

Comment: sorry, the URL 404'd because of a typo, which i just fixed.

Comment: See my latest update. I didn't realize it was returning just one instance. You need to just walk through the json data to get to what you need.

Comment: Many times when dealing with some new set of data, it's helpful just to go into the Python interactive shell and just start tearing it apart. Then put your script together based on what you've learned.

Answer (score 0):

The problme is contents.json() returns a dictionary and you are trying access this dictionaries key "{"data":{"date","average_price"}}" which is not right. Thats why you are getting TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'

Please ,dump your dictionary from contents.json() here , so we can look at the data and fix it.

Comment: I just added the dictionary, the url 404'd because i made a typo, sorry about that.

Comment: Ok, you can Always use python interactive shell , to verify your data and also test part of your code before testing it at the application level.